# How to speed learning process up in neural networks in Colaboratory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm  trying to learn neural network using this code in Colaboratory. The code works without any errors but THE MAIN PROBLEM is - this learns toooo slow(but parameters are not too big).

I have GPU as 'Hardware accelerator' in Colaboratory in 'Change runtime time' in option(for Python 3). I've tried different types of tensorflow-gpu(like in code) and it looks like the program sees gpu but it doesn't use gpu for some reason(i don't have other explanation).

If you know how to improve and more important-to speed it up I'd be very grateful:)

```
#!pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview
#!pip install tensorflow-gpu
#!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta1
#!pip install keras

!pip install -q tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta0
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
try:
    os.chdir("drive/My Drive/NN")
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print("Found GPU at: {}".format(device_name))

#import keras
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  classifier = Sequential()
  classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
  classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  classifier.add(Flatten())
  classifier.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
  classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

  from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                      rescale=1./255,
                                      shear_range=0.2,
                                      zoom_range=0.2,
                                      horizontal_flip=True
  )

  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

  training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                  'dataset/training_set',
                                                  target_size=(64, 64),
                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                  class_mode='binary'
  )

  test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                              'dataset/test_set',
                                              target_size=(64, 64),
                                              batch_size=32,
                                              class_mode='binary'
  )


  classifier.fit_generator(
                          training_set,
                          steps_per_epoch=8000,
                          epochs=25,
                          validation_data=test_set,
                          validation_steps=2000
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create one large data structure like numpy array(save it with npy and load), hdf5 etc. Training from directory really takes a lot of time. If your data is not huge you can try such a thing. That's what I found out when I switch from numpy arrays to the flow_from_directory.